# How to make Android application as executable file like JAR in Java?

Tags: android

I want to make my android application as executable file that can install in any other android emulator like JAR in java programming.If anyone know please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are called APK files. You can create them via [Eclipse](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/eclipse-adt.html) or [Ant](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/other-ide.html).

Answer (score 1):

view plaincopy to clipboardprint?

```
class Helloworld {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        System.out.println("Hello World!");  
    }  
}  

class Helloworld { 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        System.out.println("Hello World!"); 
    } 
}
```

Makefile:

view plaincopy to clipboardprint?

```
   android_dir_dx = $(ANDROID_SRC_DIR)/out/host/linux-x86/bin/dx
```

all:

```
   javac Helloworld.java  
   $(android_dir_dx) --dex --output=Helloworld.jar Helloworld.class
```

clean:

```
@rm *.jar *.class 

android_dir_dx = $(ANDROID_SRC_DIR)/out/host/linux-x86/bin/dx all: javac Helloworld.java $(android_dir_dx) --dex --output=Helloworld.jar Helloworld.class clean: @rm *.jar *.class
```

run：

```
dalvikvm -cp /Helloworld.jar Helloworld
```